# Function for an n-fold sum

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

I have sums of the form

$\sum_{j=1}^{3}\sum_{k=j+2}^{5} b_j b_k,\quad \sum_{j=1}^{3}\sum_{k=j+2}^{5}\sum_{m=k+2}^{7} b_j b_k b_m, \quad \dots$

and so forth. I am now trying to find a function that only needs a list of the ${b_n}$ and the number of summations and yields such an object. However I don't know how to proceed, as I am not aware of how to implement the number of summations as an argument or else.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just to state the obvious:  If your sum involved all indices with $j<k<m\cdots$ rather than the more restrictive indices you display, the `SymmetricPolynomial` function would be very handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should work:

```
sum[b_, n_] := 
 Block[{a}, 
  Sum[Product[b[[a[i]]], {i, 1, n}], 
   Evaluate[
    Sequence @@ 
     Table[{a[i], If[i == 1, 1, a[i - 1] + 2], 2 i + 1}, {i, 1, n}]]]]

(* Example *)
sum[Array[b, 10], 2]
(* b[1] b[3] + b[1] b[4] + b[2] b[4] + b[1] b[5] + b[2] b[5] + b[3] b[5] *)
```

As you see, I manually construct $n$ summation indices. I use `Sequence` to distribute them as arguments to `Sum`, and I also need to wrap it with `Evaluate` because `Sum` has the attribute [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html).

Comment: something like this in python
```
import itertools

def sum_product(b, n):
    combinations = itertools.combinations(b, n)
    result = sum([reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, combo) for combo in combinations])
    return result

# Example
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n = 2
result = sum_product(b, n)
print(result)  # Output: 35 (1*2 + 1*3 + 1*4 + 1*5 + 2*3 + 2*4 + 2*5 + 3*4 + 3*5 + 4*5)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

(Format[#[n_]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@ {b, i};

sum[n_Integer?Positive] := Module[{},
  i[0] = -1;
  Inactive[Sum] @@ {Times @@ (b /@ (i /@ Range[n])),
    Sequence @@ ({i[#], i[# - 1] + 2, 2 # + 1} & /@
       Range[n])}]

sum[4] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
Activate@%
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
yourSum[n_Integer] := 
 Module[{bVariables, expr, sumConditions}, 
  bVariables = Array[Subscript[b, Subscript[i, #]] &, n];
  expr = Times @@ bVariables;
  sumConditions = 
   Table[{Subscript[i, p], If[p >= 2, Subscript[i, p - 1], -1] + 2, 
     2 p + 1}, {p, 1, n}];
  Inactive[Sum] @@ ({expr}~Join~sumConditions)]

n = 6;
yourSum[n]
Activate@%
```

$$
\underset{i_1=1}{\overset{3}{\sum }}\underset{i_2=i_1+2}{\overset{5}{\sum }}\underset{i_3=i_2+2}{\overset{7}{\sum }}\underset{i_4=i_3+2}{\overset{9}{\sum }}\underset{i_5=i_4+2}{\overset{11}{\sum }}\underset{i_6=i_5+2}{\overset{13}{\sum }}b_{i_1} b_{i_2} b_{i_3} b_{i_4} b_{i_5} b_{i_6}
$$